# File Based Locking vs In-Memory Locking

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, synchronization, lucene

So I know what locks are and how they are used. I was messing around with Lucene and noticed that it uses a file (.e.g. **write.lock**) rather than an in-memory object to synchronize the multiple threads writing (most trouble some) and reading from the indexes. My question is what are the advantages of using a file?

Off the top of my head I can only think of persistence in the event that the system crashes before its able to release the lock.

Also it will be great if you can point to some blogs, papers, documents that give more info on this.

PS: I've read through the Lucene architecture which behaves similarly to Log-Segmented Trees/SSTables.

Are there implementations that use it as well and if so how is it used? How do you tell which thread holds the current file-lock (I am assuming this will revolve around file system operations)

Comment: Lucene prefers to leverage OS capabilities in several places. For instance, instead of keeping FSTs or hnsw graphs in memory in a separate data structure, it relies on files and expects them to be memory-mapped by the operating system. The reason for using file locks could be similar. I could be wrong here, this is my best guess.